# I have two NSScrollViews configured to scroll in sync. My problem is that the enclosed table headers do not scroll horizontally. Any clue?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

I am developing a Cocoa Application for macOS. I need two NSOutlineView to be in scroll sync. I have followed the well known [Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html) and it works very well. I wanted to add horizontal scrolling to the code, so I added this line of code to the NSScrollView subclass:

```
newOffset.x = changedBoundsOrigin.x;
```

after:

```
newOffset.y = changedBoundsOrigin.y;
```

It works very well, assuming that, for the moment, I assume NSOutlineView width with all columns to be equal between the two NSOutlineViews. The problem is that when scrolling horizontally, the NSOutlineView headers of the other NSOutlineView do not sync, so they do not follow. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the edit rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works and it is good for me for the moment until I implement code that keeps the column widths in sync too. The solution I have found is the following:

In the Apple provided NSScrollView subclass, declare two IBOutlets referencing the left NSTableHeaderView and the right one. This is a bit tricky in Interface Builder since you have to create first the outlets in your interface like this:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableHeaderView *leftOutLineHeaderView;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableHeaderView *rightOutLineHeaderView;
```

Then you open the interface file in a new window and connect the outlets starting from the circle in your interface file. Note that the opposite will not work, if you try to create the outlets automatically from IB that will not work.

Then, I also need a flag to tell if it is the left or the right table, given that the two outlets will both be populated for both NSScrollViews. This is the flag in my interface file:

```
@property (assign) Boolean isLeftTable;
```

I set the flag immediately after setting the NSScrollViews in sync as Apple Suggests:

```
// This is Apple taken code:

self.leftScrollView.setSynchronized(self.rightScrollView)
self.rightScrollView.setSynchronized(self.leftScrollView)

// Here I set the flag to the two NSScrollViews:

self.leftScrollView.isLeftTable = true
self.rightScrollView.isLeftTable = false
```

The preparation is finished. Now, in the synchronizedViewContentBoundsDidChange method of the example, after:

```
[[self contentView] scrollToPoint:newOffset];
```

I have inserted this:

```
if (!self.isLeftTable) {

        NSRect currentRightHeaderRect = self.rightOutLineHeaderView.frame;

        currentRightHeaderRect.origin.x = -changedBoundsOrigin.x;

        self.rightOutLineHeaderView.frame = currentRightHeaderRect;

    } else {

        NSRect currentLeftHeaderRect = self.leftOutLineHeaderView.frame;

        currentLeftHeaderRect.origin.x = -changedBoundsOrigin.x;


        self.leftOutLineHeaderView.frame = currentLeftHeaderRect;

 }
```

It works for the moment, although it needs some testing and probably refinements. Thanks a lot.